# Paypal Payments Advanced - Issue with payment processing

Tags: paypal

We have successfully implemented PayPal Payment Advance in TEST mode. Till yesterday, we were getting proper response http data from paypal after the order has been placed. However, today, after I enter test visa number and expire date/ year.. It shows following message instead of giving me back post data.

`"Thank you for your purchase, we are currently reviewing your order."`

Due to this, I am not able to work further. This is test sandbox account where i have setup PPA.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer... By mistake, i had update settings in paypal for "Payment Review" to Enable. I disabled it and got it working again. Hope this helps anyone in future to check this basic stuff first.